# Find and Replace quotes in all the entires tables, columns in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

How to `replace quotes` in all the entires tables, columns in `MySQL database` using `phpmyadmin`?

**Example** : find the  quotes `'` , replace with other quotes `’`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `tableName` SET `columnName` = REPLACE(`columnName`, '\'', '`')
```

Escape the quote with `\` character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Find and replace", located under the "Search" tab, for this purpose.

From your table, click the Search tab (which is the fourth tab in the phpMyAdmin I'm using).

On the resulting page, click "Find and replace"

[image: Find and replace tab]

Next, enter what you want to search for, which column to use, and what you want to replace it with. Also note that you have to escape both the single quote and "smart quote" characters:

[image: Find and replace]